# Query returned with an extra column in sql -ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I am wondering. I fell into an interesting suggestion from another developer. So i basically have two tables I join in a query and I want the resulting table from the query to have an extra column that comes from the table on from the joint.

Example:

```
#table A: contains rating of players, changes randomly at any date depending
#on drop of form from the players  

PID| Rating | DateChange  |
1  |    2   | 10-May-2014 |
1  |    4   | 20-May-2015 |
1  |   20   | 1-June-2015 |
2  |    4   | 1-April-2014|
3  |    4   | 5-April-2014|
2  |    3   | 3-May-2015  |

#Table B: contains match sheets. Every player has a different match sheet
#and plays different dates.

MsID | PID  | MatchDate    | Win |
 1   |  2   | 10-May-2014  |  No |
 2   |  1   | 15-May-2015  | Yes |
 3   |  3   | 10-Apr-2014  |  No |
 4   |  1   | 21-Apr-2015  | Yes |
 5   |  1   | 3-June-2015  | Yes |
 6   |  2   | 5-May-2015   |  No |

#I am trying to achieve this by running the ms-access query: i want to get
#every players rating at the time the match was played not his current
#rating. 

MsID | PID  | MatchDate    | Rating |
 1   |  2   | 10-May-2014  |    4   |
 2   |  1   | 15-May-2015  |    2   |
 3   |  3   | 10-Apr-2014  |    4   |
 4   |  1   | 21-Apr-2015  |    4   |
 5   |  1   | 3-June-2015  |    20  |
 6   |  2   | 5-May-2015   |    3   |
```

This is what I have tried below:

```
Select MsID, PID, MatchDate, A-table.rating as Rating from B-table
       left Join A-table 
          on B-table.PID = A-table.PID
             where B-table.MatchDate > A-table.Datechange;
```

any help is appreciated. The solution can be in `Vba` as long as it returns something like a view/table I can manipulate using other queries or report.

Comment: So you want the rating corresponding to the max date change on or before date of match.

Comment: yhup exactly. what I want.

Comment: I think your expected results are off for 4/1 it should be rating 2 using the 10-May-2014 as 21-Apr-2015 comes before 20-May-2015 thus it should use the 2014 date. (10-May-2014)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of this in terms of sets of data... you need a set that lists the MAX dateChange for each player's and match date.

Soo...

```
SELECT MAX(A.DateChange) MDC, A.PID, B.Matchdate
FROM B-table B
INNER Join A-table A
 on B.PID = A.PID
and A.DateChange <= B.MatchDate
GROUP BY A.PID, B.Matchdate
```

Now we take this and join it back to what you've done to limit the results in table A and B to ONLY those with that date player and matchDate (my inline table C)

```
SELECT B.MsID, B.PID, B.MatchDate, A.rating as Rating 
FROM [B-table] B
INNER JOIN [A-table] A
  on B.PID = A.PID
INNER JOIN (     
  SELECT MAX(Y.DateChange) MDC, Y.PID, Z.Matchdate
  FROM [B-table] Z
  INNER Join [A-table] Y
   on Z.PID = Y.PID
  and Y.DateChange <= Z.MatchDate
  GROUP BY Y.PID, Z.Matchdate) C
  on C.mdc = A.DateChange
 and A.PID = C.PId
 and B.MatchDate = C.Matchdate
```

I didn't create a sample for this using your data so it's **untested** but I believe the logic is sound...

Now Tested! [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31717c/3/0) using SQL server though...

My results don't match yours exactly.  I think you're expected results are wrong though for MSID 4 given rules defined.

Comment: your results dont match mine (i made a mistake), logic checked, explanation good, results more than perfect, you are a genius! :)

Comment: The real question is do you understand why this works and if the situation arises again would you recognize it and be able to apply it?  I'm all for helping, but I also like to make sure someone can fish on their own.  Anything you have questions on?

Comment: i actually understand. that's why it took me time to accept the answer. I am here everyday learning. I didn't even think of this approach. you are definetly more experienced than I am. And the explanation was pretty clear